Does a simple formal group give rise to a simple Lie algebra?
A formal group $F$ is an intermediate object between Lie group $G$ and Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$.
A formal group is called simple if it has no nontrivial sub-formal group. On the other hand, a simple Lie group is more or less defined in terms of whether the associated Lie algebra is simple (e.g., section 4).
More precisely, let $F$ be a formal group over a ring $R$ and $$F(X,Y)=X+Y+\underset{\text{quadratic terms}}{F_2(X,Y)}+\text{higher degree terms}$$ be a formal group law representing $F$, the Lie bracket is defined by
$$[x,y]=F_2(x,y)-F_2(y,x).$$
This is how a formal group (law) gives rise to a Lie algebra.
As Wikipedia says, over characteristic $0$ field, formal group laws are essentially the same as finite-dimensional Lie algebra, my question is:
Does a simple formal group over a characteristic $0$ field or ring give rise to simple Lie algebra?
Thanks

I don't think simplicity of a Lie group is defined by whether the Lie algebra is simple.  I think that most people wouldn't call $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb R)$ simple, since it has ${\pm1}$ as a non-trivial normal subgroup, but it does have simple Lie algebra $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb R)$.  (Despite this we would call it semisimple, or, to emphasise that it's semisimple with only one factor, sometimes ‘almost simple’.)

@LSpice, thanks for the comment. I found something in the answer here. You may be right about it. Anyway, if you keep aside the Lie group here, my question is what is the relationship between a simple formal group and it's Lie algebra. Does the property of a formal group of being "simple" transfer to its Lie algebra? I think there might not be a direct relationship but I may be wrong because how can the coefficients of quadratic terms of a formal group law determine if it's Lie algebra is simple.

The wiki page already mentions that the functor from the category of finite dimensional formal groups to the category of finite dimensional Lie algebras is an equivalence of categories. The simplicity is asking whether every monomorphism is either from the initial object, or the identity, and this property is preserved by categorical equivalences.

@Z.M, alright thanks. So, at least , over a characteristic $0$ field, the answer is yes. Can we say something the same thing over a characteristic $0$ ring, e. g., ring of $p$-adic integers which is an integral domain?

@LSpice This is the exact opposite of my experience, which is that most people would call $SL_2(\mathbb R)$ simple. The Wikipedia page on simple Lie groups gives the definition that "a simple Lie group is a connected non-abelian Lie group $G$ which does not have nontrivial connected normal subgroups" which fits with this.

@LSpice I don't know about most people, but some people would call $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ simple as a Lie group, but not simple as a group.

@Learner I would not call them "char 0 rings" (which I would understand as $\mathbb Q$-algebras), although this terminology is sort of common. Instead, I would call them "of mixed characteristic". For rings of mixed char, Lie algebras are ill behaved (cf. the development of partition Lie algebras), and I would not expect this to be true.

I believe over $\mathbb Z_p$ it's possible to have a simple formal group of dimension $>1$ whose underlying Lie algebra is commutative, and therefore certainly not simple. For a concrete example if you take an abelian variety of genus $3$ with good reduction and Newton polygon of Frobenius with slopes $1/3, 2/3$ then the formal group law will split at most into $1$-dimensional and $2$-dimensional pieces, but will certainly be commutative.

I was definitely too hasty in saying what most people would do!  I think I should instead have said that, in the context of algebraic groups, I think that it is reasonably common to call the algebraic group $\operatorname{SL}_2$ both semisimple and almost-simple, and just to avoid the term simple as somewhere between confusing and useless.  Historically, Borel–Tits do this; and, contemporaneously, Milne does.  (I don't regard Wiki's definition as saying much about mathematical practice, but I do attach weight to the experience of my colleagues here!)

(As evidence for why one has to be careful in the setting of algebraic groups, even with clever definitions that are careful to rule out only non-trivial, connected, normal subgroups: in positive characteristic $p$, the central $\mu_p$ in $\operatorname{SL}_p$ is connected, and certainly non-trivial!)

@WillSawin, If I understand you correctly, then you considered an abelian variety of genus 3, whose Lie algebra is commutative, and hence not simple. And then the associated formal group of dimension $3$ can have at most sub-formal groups of dimension $1$ and $2$. If it has sub-formal groups, then it is not simple, otherwise simple. But this can have either possibility. Maybe a more concrete example is required here.

@Learner The $2$-dimensional formal group would also be commutative and not simple, and that would be the counterexample.

@WillSawin, I still couldn't catch the argument here, but I am almost there. First, our aim is to prove that over $\mathbb{Z}_p$, a simple formal group law may not give a simple Lie algebra. You found an example which says "non-simple formal group law gives non-simple Lie algebra". How is a counter example? Second, you said that the associated $3$-dimensional formal group law is commutative and not simple. How do we know that this would split? Because there are simple formal group law of dimension $3$, if I am not wrong. So could you please clarify little more?

@WillSawin, Are you saying that a commutative formal group can not be simple?

Sorry, I was brief. I meant to say the 2-dimensional formal group would be commutative and hence its Lie algebra is not simple, since every commutative Lie algebra of dimension $>1$ is not simple. On the other hand, when I say the formal group splits at most into $1$- and $2$-dimensional pieces, the $2$-dimensional piece would be simple.
